# wrong notification date

Tags: objective-c

i am setting notification,
i can see that the NSDate that i use to set it is `2012-10-10 08:37:55 +0000`
but, then it NSLog another date to fire when i set a notification:

```
 Notification will be shown on: 2011-10-10 08:37:55 +0000
```

the code is :

```
NSLog(@"mode:%d",[memoryInstance getEditMode]);
NSLog(@"schedule for sound:%@",number);
NSLog(@"DATE :%@",self.date); //different from the one comes next

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

   NSDateFormatter *dateFormat =  [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] autorelease]  ;
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
 NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:self.date]; //!!
 NSDate *notificationDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];



localNotification.fireDate = notificationDate;
NSLog(@"Notification will be shown on: %@",localNotification.fireDate); //different!

localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"You have something to do.."];
localNotification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View details", nil);

NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:number forKey:kTimerNameKey];
localNotification.userInfo=userInfo;

localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber =-1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

whats happen is that my notification is comes at the moment i set it. its in the past.

Answer (score 0):

got it.
i had to use yyyy for the formatter.
YYYY is for weeks in year.

Comment: it's not **weeks in year**, it's    
*'Year (in "Week of Year" based calendars)'* [Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/report/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns)